# Get last iteration of failed fit parameters in curvefit/scipy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

When fitting with curvefit within scipy, is there any way for me to access the last iteration of a fit that failed? I'm having an issue where very similar data sets with similar features are blowing up during the fit, and I would like to see if the fitting algorithm is getting anywhere near a realistic solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You could backdoor it through your function storing the passed parameters of the last call. Kludgy but it will work...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs on `curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), additional keyword arguments are passed to `leastsq` which `curve_fit` calls. So (in recent versions of SciPy) I think you can pass `full_output=True` to `curve_fit` to obtain the information: `popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier` described in the [`leastsq` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq):

- `infodict`: a dictionary of optional outputs
- `errmsg`: A string message giving information about the cause of failure.
- `ier`: An integer flag. If it is equal to 1, 2, 3 or 4, the solution was found. Otherwise, the solution was not found.